How does Landauer's Principle resolve Maxwell's Demon?
Ok so I'm going to be as clear as I can be in this question which means over-explaining some things that I know most people reading this probably have a pretty good understanding of, just to make absolutely clear what it is that I'm asking.
Maxwell's Demon is a thought experiment conceived by James Maxwell that imagines two chambers of gas, initially at the same temperature. They're separated by a wall, with a tiny door set into it. A 'demon' - some kind of tiny entity with the ability to perceive things and carry out simple actions - is able to open and close this door.
Let's say that the demon opens and closes the door 200 times in an hour, totally at random. In doing so, it will do some amount of work - it will use a certain amount of energy - but the gas won't really be changed. The entropy of the demon will increase, the entropy of the gas won't change.
Now let's say that instead, the demon opens and closes the door 200 times in an hour, but in a much more specific way. It opens and closes the door only so that more energetic molecules of gas go to the left chamber, amd cooler molecules go to the right chamber. It will do the same amount of work and use the same amount of energy, but a temperature difference will be created between the two chambers. The entropy of the demon will increase by the same amount, but the entropy of the gas will fall.
The Second Law of Thermodynamics states that the entropy of a closed system must always increase. ie, that if you decrease the entropy of the gas by some amount A, then the entropy of the demon must increase by some amount B > A such that the total entropy of the gas-demon system increases.
I'm being very specific about how I formulate this problem because people often produce a naive answer that 'oh, the demon just does work and increases entropy moving the door, which satisfies the Second Law', but by discussing the case where the demon just operates the door randomly the problem with that answer is made clear.
My issue is that a solution to the paradox is often attributed to Rolf Landauer, but I'm not entirely sure how his answer doesn't suffer from the exact same problem.
Leo Szilard - the person who later discovered nuclear chain reaction - argued that in order to measure the energy of molecules, the demon has to expend some amount of energy, which is extra work and an extra increase in entropy compared to that required for just operating the door, and accounts for the difference.
Landauer, a physicist at Bell Labs, as far as I understand his argument, basically argued that measuring this information isn't the solution, because there are irreversible measurement processes that do not increase entropy. He argued instead that, in accordance with what's now called Landauer's Principle after him, destroying stored information must increase thermodynamic entropy, and that if the demon measures information about the energy of a particular molecule it will, eventually, have to discard that information.
I'm not sure if I actually understand this argument.
My issue is that, as previously established, the demon can just randomly open and close the door and have the same increase of entropy as a systematic sorting, so this specific increase in entropy isn't associated with said sorting process.
But equally, the demon could surely measure, store, and then erase the information - and then do nothing with it, and just keep moving the door randomly. It'd increase entropy by the same amount, but just like the earlier point, that increase has nothing specific to do with the sorting. The demon is obligated to do those things if it wants to sort, but it isn't obligated to sort if it wants to do those things.
I'm also not sure if I understand Landauer's points as part of his argument that a) destroying information requires more energy than collecting it b) a system cannot hold some amount of information - say, the amount needed to sort 200 molecules - in theory forever.
Can someone please explain why Landauer's argument is considered a good solution to me?

Entropy in the context of thermodynamics is an emergent property, and the second law is based on an inherently probabilistic argument. Even without the demon, there is an extremely small chance that if you open the separating door and then close it, the molecules will be sorted as you described the demon doing, decreasing the entropy. All the demon does is turn this unlikely possibility into an absolute certainty. Also, I'm not sure what it means for the entropy of the demon to increase/decrease.
